# Rspec debug - view page source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Is there a way in rspec to view the page source as a debug, such as if I log in a user in a controller test to do some action - can I dump that pages source to the console so I can see what page their on?

Capybara has `save_and_open_page`, but this is rspec, not capybara - so whats the equivalent if there is one? (I just want to see the source, not the actual page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do you testing controllers available `response`.
For example

```
its 'have show ' do
  get :show, id: event
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  expect(response).to render_template('show')
  expect(response.body.scan(%r|#{event.name}|).present?).to be_true
  expect(@assigns['event'].id).to eq(event.id)
end
```

in `responce.body` - you page html
but the default setting `Rspec` is not to render a page so you need add in `spec_helper`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.render_views
end
```